# Is there a JavaScript implementation of OGC GeoSPARQL functions?

Tags: javascript, jena, graphdb, rdf4j, geosparql

I am aware of various Java implementations of OGC GeoSPARQL standard, provided by RDF4J, Jena, GraphDB and other vendors. Now I am looking for JavaScript libraries that implement whole set of GeoSPARQL functions, or some subset of them.

I tried searching for RDF4J, Jena and GraphDB JavaScript implementations of GeoSPARQL functions, but I haven't found any.

Comment: I don't know anything about GeoSPARQL, but a quick search turned up [this GitHub issue thread including a JS implementation](https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogc-geosparql/issues/59) and [this version which seems to be tailored for a specific framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/comunica-geosparql).

Comment: Thanks for the links but unfortunately `Comunica geoSPARQL` only "supports" two GeoSPARQL functions and I haven't checked if those implementations are valid either. And for the `ogc-geosparql` `Contacting implementers` thread, maybe I can go through the list of vendors once again, but I don't think that any of them provide JS implementation I need right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SparqlJS :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sparqljs

This library doesn't have the full implementation of `GeoSPARQL`, but it does support the basic geospatial functions and operators.

Turf.js :
https://turfjs.org

It is a more general-purpose geospatial library, although not specifically designed for `GeoSPARQL`, it still has some sets of geospatial functions.

Comment: Which `GeoSPARQL` functions are supported by `SparqlJS`?

Comment: It supports some basic functions such as ```sfWithin``` and ```sfIntersects```, but it does not support all ```GeoSPARQL functions```,  you may need to  implement some of the functionality yourself.

Comment: Turf.js turned out to be a great source of functions that can be adjusted to comply with GeoSPARQL.